# Xml Category on product feed

Tags: php, xml, xsd, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

i want to post products to amazon to category of "SportsMemorabilia", using the mws product feed.

i looked over the documentation, it is hard to understand, i also download the xsd to see the xml structure 
but still it dosent working.

for this xml is sent (it is only the category part, i also sending all other elements of the product xml..)

```
<ProductData> 
<SportsMemorabilia> 
<ProductType>SportsMemorabilia</ProductType> 
</SportsMemorabilia> 
</ProductData>
```

it give me this error

```
<Result> 
<MessageID>0</MessageID> 
<ResultCode>Error</ResultCode> 
<ResultMessageCode>5000</ResultMessageCode> 
<ResultDescription>XML Parsing Error at Line 104, Column 26: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'SportsMemorabilia' is not complete. One of '{AuthenticatedBy}' is expected.</ResultDescription> 
</Result>
```

please, write to me how the xml should look like in order it to work,

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the current version, this is the **minimum** XML that should pass the published XSD. It doesn't mean it'll work, as functionality built in the service may do additional validation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<SportsMemorabilia>
    <ProductType>SportsMemorabilia</ProductType>
    <AuthenticatedBy>AuthenticatedBy1</AuthenticatedBy>
    <ConditionProvidedBy>ConditionProvidedBy1</ConditionProvidedBy>
    <ConditionRating>ConditionRating1</ConditionRating>
</SportsMemorabilia>
```

To access the services you need to have an account setup; you have to also fill in the other two elements, at least.

I would strongly suggest you to walk through the [document posted here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V149158196_.pdf)... At least the minimum above should get you over XSD validation errors.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer, i try what you wrote and i get this error


<Result>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
<ResultMessageCode>8060</ResultMessageCode>



<ResultDescription>The Product with SKU [mx_190218932015] cannot be matched to an existing product for the following reason: (authenticated_by,graded_by is/are not provided; ). For more details, see http://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/errorcode/8060</ResultDescription>
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <SKU>mx_190218932015</SKU>
    </AdditionalInfo>
   </Result>